# Regex en java para normalizar nombres compuestos

Tags: java, regex

Para el desarrollo de una aplicación necesito normalizar nombres de personas y dividirlos en nombre, primer apellido y segundo apellido, siendo éste último opcional. Se tienen que admitir y normalizar correctamente nombres con un nombre y dos apellidos, nombres con nombre y un apellido y nombres con nombre y/o apellidos compuestos.

Por ejemplo:
Juan José Pérez García pasaría a ser un objeto como el siguiente:

```
{
  nombre: "Juan José",
  primerApellido: "Pérez",
  segundoApellido: "García"
}
```

Juan José de Castro y García pasaría a ser un objeto como el siguiente:

```
{
  nombre: "Juan José",
  primerApellido: "de Castro",
  segundoApellido: "y García"
}
```

Pedro González pasaría a ser un objeto como el siguiente:

```
{
  nombre: "Pedro",
  primerApellido: "González",
  segundoApellido: null
}
```

Y Pedro González López pasaría a ser un objeto como el siguiente:

```
{
  nombre: "Pedro",
  primerApellido: "González",
  segundoApellido: "López"
}
```

Espero haberme explicado, gracias por adelantado.

Código actual sin usar regex, siendo una solución a medias que no me gusta:

```
static final List<String> PREFIXES = List.of("de", "i", "del", "y");

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] fullNames = {
                "Jose García Sánchez",
                "Maria Carmen González Pérez",
                "Jose Maria del Domingo de Pilar",
                "Pedro Tomás Lagos y Fernández",
                "Isabel Alonso i Jiménez"
        };

        for (String fullName : fullNames) {
            FullName nameComponents = parseName(fullName);
            System.out.println("Full Name: " + fullName);
            System.out.println("First Name: " + nameComponents.firstName);
            System.out.println("Last Name 1: " + nameComponents.lastName1);
            System.out.println("Last Name 2: " + nameComponents.lastName2);
            System.out.println();
        }


    }

    public static FullName parseName(String name){
        FullName fullName = new FullName();
        int index = name.lastIndexOf(" ");
        String shortenedString = name.substring(0,index);
        String currentValue = name.substring(index+1);
        index = shortenedString.lastIndexOf(" ");
        String lastWordBeforeIndex = shortenedString.substring(index + 1);

        fullName.lastName2 = PREFIXES.contains(lastWordBeforeIndex) ? lastWordBeforeIndex + " " + currentValue : currentValue;


        shortenedString = shortenedString.substring(0,index);
        currentValue = name.substring(index+1,name.substring(index+1).indexOf(" ") + index + 1);
        lastWordBeforeIndex = shortenedString.substring(index);
        shortenedString = shortenedString.substring(index);
        index = shortenedString.lastIndexOf(" ");
        fullName.lastName1 = PREFIXES.contains(lastWordBeforeIndex) ? lastWordBeforeIndex + " " + currentValue : currentValue;

        return fullName;
    }

    static class FullName {
        String firstName;
        String lastName1;
        String lastName2;
    }
```

Comment: Saludos, lo siento en SO-es no hacemos tareas ni exámenes, debes agregar lo que intentaste hacer para resolver el problema, recuerda que siempre puedes [editar tu pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/610043/edit). ;)

Comment: ¿Cómo diferenciás qué es un nombre, un apellido, un nombre compuesto y un apellido compuesto?

Comment: Y tal como te han dicho, muestra un [repro] de lo que has intentado hasta el momento. Lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Comment: No tengo la mayoria de lo que he probado, ya que he estado probando con varias expresiones regulares y ninguna me ha funcionado como esperaba, además de otras pruebas sin éxito. Al final lo he intentado hacer por java sin usar regex, pero no me gustaba como quedaba y por eso he abierto la pregunta. Añadiré lo más próximo a lo que he intentado editando la pregunta @Israel-ICM

Comment: @padaleiana Esa parte es la que no tengo clara a nivel de regex, habia pensado contar el número de espacios para definirlo, o hacer-lo todo por java sin usar regex, pero hay tantas variables que acaba siendo muy poco legible. Un nombre compuesto sería el ejemplo que he puesto de Juan José de Castro y García por ejemplo

Comment: ¿Podrías tú decir cuáles son el nombre y apellidos -compuestos si hubiere- de *Miguel Gregorio Antonio Ignacio Hidalgo y Costilla Gallaga Mandarte y Villaseñor*? Si puedes explicarle a otro humano, tal vez podamos enseñarle a la computadora.

Comment: No tratamos casos tan rebuscados, como mucho nos encontramos con el caso que he comentado de un nombre compuesto por 2 palabras, y dos apellidos con un prefijo cada uno. El problema es poder separar esos nombres a la vez que los que tienen solamente un nombre y un apellido sin más, manteniendo la legibildad del código @Sal

Answer (score 0):

Puedes aplicar lo siguiente de forma simple.

```
String partes[] = codigoEscrito.split(" ");
        String nombres = "";
        String apellidos = "";
        
        for (int p = 0; p < partes.length; p++) {
            nombres += p <= 1 ? partes[p]+" " : " ";
            apellidos += p > 1 ? partes[p]+" " : " ";
        }
```